# Angular component condition only show when page is reloaded

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7

On my app.component.html I have a condition to show a component if I am on a certain route:

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="router.url === '/home'">
  <app-slider></app-slider>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

This works when the page loads first time but when I go to another route and then come back to the home route it doesn't load so I have to reload the page for the component to show up.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about your requirement

Comment: Basically <app-slider></app-slider> only appears when I'm in the home router but when I navigate to another route and then click the home router the condition doesn't work. If only works when I reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check for activated route each time.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(res => {
    // array of route parts here
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with: // array of route parts here ?

Comment: console.log(res); kindly check the output.

Comment: It might a little more helpful to link to the docs too, as then @KevinPorche would be able to research that the res is an observable of type ```UrlSegment[]``` https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#activatedroute

Comment: It's return this: 0: UrlSegment
parameterMap: (...)
parameters: {}
path: ""

Comment: @KevinPorche You can try `toString()` on response. this will give you the route in string format.
like this: `res.toString() `.
Here is the link https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment

Comment: try this `res[0].toString()`